# How to make a jar file from scala

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I have read online that it is possible to create a jar file from scala code that could be run from the cli. All have written is the following code. How do I make a jar file from it? I am using sbt 0.13.7.

```
object Main extends App {
    println("Hello World from Scala!")
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To be able to perform complex build tasks with Scala, you have to use SBT as a build tool: it's a default scala-way of creating application packages. To add SBT support to your project, just create a `build.sbt` file in root folder:

```
name := "hello-world"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

mainClass := Some("com.example.Hello")
```

To build a jar file with your application in case if you have no external dependencies, you can run `sbt package` and it will build a `hello-world_2.11_1.0.jar` file with your code so you can run it with `java -jar hello-world.jar`. But you definitely will have to include some dependencies with your code, at least because of a Scala runtime.

Use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to build a fat jar with all your dependencies. To install it, add a line

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

to your `project/plugins.sbt` file (and create it if there's no such file) and run `sbt assembly` task from console.

Comment: what would I write in my build.sbt file?

Comment: @eddard.stark nothing, this is a build dependency, not a runtime dependency.

Comment: It is giving me a warning no main classes.
Is that an issue?

Comment: @eddard.stark You need to change mainClass field to point to your main class. `mainClass := Some("Main")` in case you do not have packages.

Comment: It creates a hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar file in target/scala-2.11 directory. But I am unable to run that file cause I am getting an error of "NoClassDefFoundError".

Comment: @eddard.stark what class is missing? Did you use `sbt package` or `sbt assembly` for building jar file?

Comment: I have used `sbt package`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: As I've mentioned (not very clear though), `sbt package` creates a jar file with your code only, but without and dependencies (*and without scala stdlib*). You have to either add scala-library*.jar to your runtime classpath, or use `sbt assembly`, which will bundle it into a single jar.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to `sbt`, consider also this plain command line,

```
scalac hello.scala -d hello.jar
```

which creates the jar file. Run it with

```
scala hello.jar
```

Also possible is to script the source code by adding this header

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#
```

and calling the main method with `Main.main(args)` (note `chmod +x hello.sh` to make the file executable). Here `savecompiled` will create a jar file on the first invocation.

Comment: I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try your answer on OP's code.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this SBT plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

I created Linux Debian packages with this plugin (Windows MSI should be possible as well).

Answer (score 2):

`sbt: publishLocal`
then go to the target folder, probably called `scala-2.**`