# spark-submit for a .scala file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been running some test spark scala code using probably a bad way of doing things with spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=Stuffffit --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jsparkCluster.scala
```

This would execute my code on spark and pop into the shell when done.

Now that I am trying to run this on a cluster, I think I need to use spark-submit, to which I thought would be:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=Stuffffit --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jsparkCluster.scala
```

but it does not like the .scala file, somehow does it have to be compiled into a class?    the scala code is a simple scala file with several helper classes defined in it and no real main class so to speak.   I don't see int he help files but maybe I am missing it, can I just spark-submit a file or do I have to somehow give it the class?  Thus changing my scala code?

I did add this to my scala code too:

went from this

```
val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("neo4jspark")


val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

To this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://192.20.0.71:7077")
```

Comment: Based on some docs for [spark-submit](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-submit.html) looks like it takes in a jar file. You might need to compile your scala code to a jar (there are different ways to do this) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576222/how-to-make-a-jar-file-from-scala

Comment: I kind of thought so, I will look into this, I thought there was an easier option I might of missed.  I also think the packages I was loading does not work the same in spark-submit either.

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 quick and dirty ways of doing this:

1. **Without modifying the scala file**

Simply use the spark shell with the `-i` flag:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell -i neo4jsparkCluster.scala`

2. **Modifying the scala file to include a main method**

a. Compile:

`scalac -classpath <location of spark jars on your machine> neo4jsparkCluster`

b. Submit it to your cluster:

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --class <qualified class name> --master <> .`

Answer (score 4):

You will want to package your scala application with sbt and include Spark as a dependency within your build.sbt file.

See the self contained applications section of the quickstart guide for full instructions https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the following Hello World example for Spark which packages your application as @zachdb86 already mentioned.

[spark-hello-world](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-hello-world)