# How to fix error and what causes: Error: Main method is not static in class

Tags: java, scala, jar, program-entry-point

I am getting this error:

> Error: Main method is not static in class oracle.Execution$, please define the main method as:
> public static void main(String[] args)

When I run the command:

> java -jar MyProgram.jar oracle.Execution

But I can't figure out why is it happening. This is my code (very simple)

```
package oracle

import publish.PublishFile

object Execution {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val reader = OracleReader()

        val SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator")
        val END_PATH = s"${System.getProperty("user.dir")}${SEPARATOR}testingDumpResults"
        PublishFile().publishThroughFile(END_PATH, reader)

    }

}
```

I've also tried this but the same error occurs:

```
object Execution extends App {
        val reader = OracleReader()

        val SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator")
        val END_PATH = s"${System.getProperty("user.dir")}${SEPARATOR}testingDumpResults"
        PublishFile().publishThroughFile(END_PATH, reader)

}
```

Also when I run the program using the InteliJ interface it runs and I can't seem to find what is the cause of the error.

Comment: Does this link help? [How to make a jar file from scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576222/how-to-make-a-jar-file-from-scala)

Comment: @NickGris just tried and got the same error

Comment: How did you build your **JAR**? Note that a **JAR** needs a manifest file, usually build tools take care of that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez on my first attempt I used the InteliJ build artifact feature that put the manifest at src\main\resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF. The same happens when I use assembly as per the previous link.

Comment: @Shelen no idea about the **ItenliJ** feature and I would not trust it to work correctly. However, I have used **sbt-assembly** many times in the past and it always worked as expected. Can you please create a small **Github** repo with all your code, build definition, etc, and add in the `README.md` the commands you used to generate and test the **JAR**. I will take a look and if I find something I will open a PR with the fixes.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're defining Execution as a Scala object correctly. However, when you're trying to execute it using the java command with the -jar option, Java expects a Java class with a main method, not a Scala object.

To execute a Scala program packaged in a JAR file, you should use the scala command instead of java. Here's how you can run your Scala program:

```
scala -cp MyProgram.jar oracle.Execution
```

Comment: This works on my local machine but on the deployment server for testing I don't have access to scala commands